# what happens if you do make clean in the gcc 4.9 configure directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, gcc4.9

i just installed gcc4.9 in my home/myname/gcc-4.9 directory, I did the following:

```
1. cd /home/myname/gcc-source (where i have to run the config script)
2. ./configure --prefix=/home/myname/gcc-4.9  (and flags) 
3. make && make install  
4. now all the lib, bin, include etc folders are in /home/myname/gcc-4.9  directory.
```

I accidentally did a make clean in the /home/myname/gcc-source/  directory and it started removing a lot of files which were make'ed.

Will my gcc still work ? I didnt see any files getting deleted from /home/myname/gcc-4.9  folder as such.

Or should i do ./configure and make && make install again ?

Comment: yes it will work. "make install" installs everything under /home/myname/gcc-4.9. make clean just removes .o and exe but it does not touch install path

Comment: `make clean` does not affect installed files so it's safe to do. You can also remove the entire source tree and build directory if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Will my gcc still work ?

Yes!

`make && make install` consists of two parts:

1. `make` - compile (create executable)
2. `make install` - copy compiled executable to appropriate directory

`make clean` undoes result of `make`, but does not touch result of `make install` (i.e. your program stays installed)